Map JSON with multiple unknown fields to Java POJO
I am trying to map the below JSON to java POJO. Below is the JSON.
{
  "customObject": {
    "value": {
      "config-1": {
        "configurationName": {
          "de": "Das ist ein Text",
          "en": "Hospitalization Cover"
        },
        "key": "hospitalization-cover",
        "mandatory": false,
        "type": "options",
        "options": {
          "1Lakh": {
            "label": "1 Lakh",
            "priceType": "fixed",
            "price": "200",
            "default": "true"
          },
          "2Lakh": {
            "label": "2 Lakh",
            "priceType": "fixed",
            "price": "400"
          },
          "3Lakh": {
            "label": "3 Lakh",
            "priceType": "fixed",
            "price": "450"
          },
          "4Lakh": {
            "label": "4 Lakh",
            "priceType": "fixed",
            "price": "500"
          },
          "5Lakh": {
            "label": "5 Lakh",
            "priceType": "fixed",
            "price": "550"
          },
          "6Lakh": {
            "label": "6 Lakh",
            "priceType": "fixed",
            "price": "650"
          },
          "7Lakh": {
            "label": "7 Lakh",
            "priceType": "fixed",
            "price": "780"
          }
        }
      },
      "config-2": {
        "configurationName": {
          "de": "Das ist ein Text",
          "en": "OPD Cover"
        },
        "key": "opd-cover",
        "mandatory": false,
        "type": "number",
        "options": {
          "OPDCover10k": {
            "label": "10,000",
            "priceType": "calculated",
            "priceFactor": 0.2,
            "default": "true"
          },
          "OPDCover15k": {
            "label": "15,000",
            "priceType": "calculated",
            "priceFactor": 0.27
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

I have created below POJO to map it.
package com.edu.epam.graphQLSearch.custom.graphlQLqueries;

public class GqCustomObject {

    private GqConfigCustomPOValue customObject;

    public GqConfigCustomPOValue getCustomObject() {
        return customObject;
    }

    public void setCustomObject(GqConfigCustomPOValue customObject) {
        this.customObject = customObject;
    }
}


Above POJO is working fine.
Below is the second POJO.
package com.edu.epam.graphQLSearch.custom.graphlQLqueries;

public class GqConfigCustomPOValue {


    public GqCustomPOCAList value;

    public GqCustomPOCAList getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(GqCustomPOCAList value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

Below is the third POJO
package com.edu.epam.graphQLSearch.custom.graphlQLqueries;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import java.util.List;


public class GqCustomPOCAList {


    public List<GqCustomPOConfigAttributes> config;

    public List<GqCustomPOConfigAttributes> getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    public void setConfig(List<GqCustomPOConfigAttributes> config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}

Below is the fourth POJO
package com.edu.epam.graphQLSearch.custom.graphlQLqueries;

public class GqCustomPOConfigAttributes {

    private String configurationName;
    private String key;
    private boolean mandatory;
    private String type;
    private Object options;

    public String getConfigurationName() {
        return configurationName;
    }

    public void setConfigurationName(String configurationName) {
        this.configurationName = configurationName;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public boolean isMandatory() {
        return mandatory;
    }

    public void setMandatory(boolean mandatory) {
        this.mandatory = mandatory;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Object getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(Object options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
}

I am getting issue with POJO GqCustomPOCAList. Here, I am not able to define key "config-1" as it is mentioned in JSON.
When I define it as public List<GqCustomPOConfigAttributes> config; I get the error
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "config-1" (class com.edu.epam.graphQLSearch.custom.graphlQLqueries.GqCustomPOCAList), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "config"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"customObject":{"value":{"config-1":{"configurationName":{"de":"Das ist ein Text","en":"Hospitalization Cover"},"key":"hospitalization-cover","mandatory":false,"type":"options","options":{"1Lakh":{"label":"1 Lakh","priceType":"fixed","price":"200","default":"true"},"2Lakh":{"label":"2 Lakh","priceType":"fixed","price":"400"},"3Lakh":{"label":"3 Lakh","priceType":"fixed","price":"450"},"4Lakh":{"label":"4 Lakh","priceType":"fixed","price":"500"},"5Lakh":{"label":"5 Lakh","priceType":"fixed","pri"[truncated 447 chars]; line: 1, column: 39] (through reference chain: com.edu.epam.graphQLSearch.custom.graphlQLqueries.GqCustomObject["customObject"]->com.edu.epam.graphQLSearch.custom.graphlQLqueries.GqConfigCustomPOValue["value"]->com.edu.epam.graphQLSearch.custom.graphlQLqueries.GqCustomPOCAList["config-1"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)

I am not able to define variable as below in java class
public List<GqCustomPOConfigAttributes> config-1;

Is there any better way to handle this?

Sometimes it's better to just use JsonNode class rather than a POJO. For example, what if there where more than two config values? You have no JSON lists here, so the arraylist isn't valid

You can use @JsonProperty("config-1")

Your json structure doesn't match your object structure.  Do you have the access to modify the json?

When you have multiple unknown fields, the best way to parse them is with the @JsonAnySetter annotation. This annotation allows you to add an unknown key-value pair within a specific field of your choice (usually a Map).
Here is a working demo parsing your json at OneCompiler.
Here is the list of suggestions/corrections in your code:
class GqCustomPOCAList {

    // 1. Do not use a List to parse an unknown number of configs,
    // use instead the @JsonAnyGetter annotation and a Map to add every config with their name as the key (config-1, config-2, etc.)
    public Map<String, GqCustomPOConfigAttributes> config;

    // 2. initializing the Map so that it can be used by the method marked with @JsonAnySetter
    public GqCustomPOCAList(){
        config = new HashMap<>();
    }

    // 3. Method to add a generic config to the Map
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addConfig(String cofigName, GqCustomPOConfigAttributes value){
        config.put(cofigName, value);
    }

    //... other methods ...
}

class GqCustomPOConfigAttributes {

    // 4. configurationName appears to be a Map<String, String> within your Json, not a String
    private Map<String, String> configurationName;
    private String key;
    private boolean mandatory;
    private String type;

    // 5. Do not use a generic Object to represent your option, define a class Option with the possible fields.
    // 6. Again, if the possible options are unknown, use a Map<String, Option> and the @JsonAnySetter annotation
    private Map<String, Option> options;

    // 7. initializing the Map so that it can be used by the method marked with @JsonAnySetter
    public GqCustomPOConfigAttributes(){
        configurationName = new HashMap<>();    
    }

    // 8. Method to add a generic option to the Map
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addOption(String optionName, Option option){
        options.put(optionName, option);
    }

    // ... other methods ...
}

class Option {
    private String label;
    private String priceType;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private BigDecimal priceFactor;

    // 9. the 'default' property must be renamed as default is a java keyword,
    // use @JsonProperty to bind it to the field 'default' within the Json
    @JsonProperty("default")
    private boolean isDefault;

    // ... other methods ...
}

